# How is Request/Reply best implemented using JMS and Spring Integration (2.2)

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a simple request reply test implemented using the following configuration:

```
<int:gateway id="myGateway"
    service-interface="TestGateway" 
    default-request-channel="sendingChannel"
    default-reply-channel="replyChannel"
    default-reply-timeout="2000"
    />

<int:channel id="sendingChannel" />
<int:channel id="replyChannel" />

<int-jms:outbound-gateway id="myJmsGateway"
    connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
    request-channel="sendingChannel"
    request-destination-name="outQueue"
    reply-channel="replyChannel"
    reply-destination-name="outQueueReply"
    receive-timeout="60000"
    />
```

and the Interface:

```
public interface TestGateway {
    @Gateway
    public String requestReply(@Header("myHeaderKey") String headerValue, String data);
}
```

While the above configuration does "work" I have the following reservations.

1. The configuration feels redundant. Extra gateway and two extra channels required.  Both gateways implement a reply timeout (although the `int:gateway` timeout doesn't fire when connected to a `int-jms:outbound-gateway`).
2. The semantics of the gateway method change depending on what is implementing the request/reply. On Timeout the `int-jms:outbound-gateway` will throw an exception, which will propagate to the user of `TestGateway`.  If the config is changed to replace `int-jms:outbound-gateway` the `int:gateway` will return null.

Given this the client code has to both handle null and the exception in the same way.

Are there any better ways to wire up the gateways?  One option would be to change the `int:channel's` to `PollableChannel's` which solves problem 2 at the expense of an extra thread pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need to configure reply channels; by default the jms gateway (with no reply channel) will return the message to the inbound gateway automatically.
2. When using direct channels, the messaging gateway's timeout only starts when the thread tries to receive any reply that was returned from the flow.

You can avoid the different semantics (null Vs exception) by adding an `error-channel` to the inbound gateway.

It's important to understand that `myGateway` isolates your client from the messaging system, you code to the interface only. Of course you could inject the JMS gateway directly but then you've added dependencies to your code. With a messaging gateway, you can change technologies without making any changes to your client code. You can also unit test your code by providing a test implementation of `TestGateway`. This is a powerful feature of Spring Integration.

Comment: Yes, reply channels are not strictly necessary but helpful when processing errors.  Otherwise you get an error message which references a temporary channel.

Comment: The error channel solution works - however you now have two timeouts again.  The first gateway `myGateway` will receive the timeout reply from the `myJmsGateway`, route to the error channel, then wait for its timeout before returning null.  Ideally it would return immediately after receiving the timeout from the `myJmsGateway`.

Comment: The isolation is great for testing.  The issue is the extra gateway & associated configuration.  Providing the interface directly to the `int-jms:outbound-gateway` or something similar would eliminate the extra unnecessary config while still giving all the isolation benefits.

Comment: injecting the JMS gateway directly (id bean with id `myJmsGateway`) just gives you an EventDrivenConsumer.  Not a very helpful object and would break the isolation in anycase.

Comment: Right; the messaging gateway provides the abstraction over the messaging system; I guess I don't understand what you are asking for. The whole point of the abstraction is you can add components (if you wish) between the gateways, to enhance, transform or whatever the message, without the client application having to know about it.

Comment: My confusion is in thinking that the `int-jms:outbound-gateway` was just a subtype of `int:gateway`.  If that was the case I could just replace one with the other and have a simpler config, while the client code would remain exactly the same. 

Coming from a non spring-integration direction I was looking for a solution that directly injected the jms gateway.  Then if requirements change I could inject a different object (http gateway etc).  All objects implementing the same interface.

Thanks for your comments, you've been very helpful.  Marking this answer as accepted.

Comment: Ah - yes - I can see where you were coming from - however, for example, let's say you want to swap out the JMS gateway for a SOAP WS gateway - in that case you might need to enhance the message between the client and the GW (e.g. add a SOAP Action header). The client wouldn't need to know any of that.